Title of a book about a fairy princess
It's a book about a little girl who thinks she's a fairy princess I believe and there's lots of pink.  And she has wings and I believe a star wand and at one point of the book she's trying to cast a spell on someone saying flogin boggan Biddle noggin. Or something to that effect.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Is it a picture book?

For the sake of the site, is it actually fantasy literature where she has wings and/or magic and/or is a fairy? Or is this a story about a girl who just believes that she is a fairy princess, has toy wings, and is pretending to cast spells?

@FuzzyBoots Sounds like there's a purely fantastical secondary subcreation in your second example… both examples of fantasy?

:-D That feels like it's getting a bit meta.

@FuzzyBoots - It's a story about a little girl imagining all the things she'd do if she were a fairy. I'd argue that it's on-topic because the fantastical elements, although clearly existing in Alice's mind, form the entirety of the book; https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3453/20774

{waggles hand} No downvote from me, and I won't vote to close, but it doesn't match for me.

@FuzzyBoots - It's definitely a waggly-hand sorta question. The important thing is that we've found it and that I've got some more rep

Could this be Alice the Fairy by David Shannon?

Of course, I also have a Magic Mirror."Mirror, mirror, on the wall,
who’s the fairiest of them all?" Well, what do you know - it’s me,
Alice! Thank you, Mirror; Fairy dust is very useful. I use it to turn oatmeal into cake.
Casting spells is another important part of being a fairy. Watch me
make my dog float on the ceiling.
Hocus Pocus croakin Docus!
Howkin
Towkin Riggin Fowkin!
Doggin Floggin Biddle Noggin!!
Okay… that one needs a little work.






Note that Alice is imagining what it would be like to be a fairy, but the story itself is fairly grounded.
